# Batch file unable to access Program files X86

Tags: windows-7, windows, batch

I need to be able to run a simple ROBOCOPY on a backup file that is location in: C:\Program Files (x86). I get an error when I try to test I get an error saying that it doesn't like the x86. I have also tried %programfiles% and that didn't resolve it either.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: Use `"`s around names with spaces.

Comment: Note that `%programfiles%` is (64-bit) `C:\Program Files`; if you want to use the variable (which you don't need to) for (32-bit) `C:\Program Files (x86)` it's `%programfiles(x86)%`.

Comment: The quotes totally worked! Thanks! I really appreciate your help!

Comment: You should really have included the line, then shown if it's really just a batch file issue(unlikely) or if it's also generally from the command line in which case nothing to do with batch files

Comment: @barlop - this was 2.5 years ago.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey so what. Somebody else can view this question, this site is primarily a QnA database, and both a Q and an A should be quality

Comment: Comments are not answers.

Answer (score 1):

There are two way to do this.

1. Use Double-quotes as stated by @DavidPostill
2. Use the respective 8.3 name "PROGRA~2".

To determine the 8.3 name of the folder:

- Open a command prompt
- Type "dir /x" this will list the files and folder and their respective 8.3 notation

Comment: Thanks GeekyDaddy, I tried the 8.3 trick first, but I don't think the directory included the 8.3 name (as far as I could tell, but that might be user error as opposed to it not being there :))

Answer (score 1):

The use of single or double quotes referenced by @GeekyDaddy & mentioned initially by @DavidPostill - is whats required.

The 8.3 equivalent is as praise worthy.

Another tip to get exact / literal paths in (CMD) command-prompt is to start with a quoted string (`"C:\P"`) such as:

```
"C:\P"
```

<kbd>tab</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd> + ... # & so-forth for each suggestion

This would give you suggestion which it ought to auto-complete for first / every match thereafter depending on the number of characters you'd typed.
A belated version of bash-completion by 20+ years :-)

Comment: Great info! I really appreciate it. I am just learning how all this stuff works and I really appreciate the direction you have given!